# Issue with Url key change for product in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, url-rewrite, seo, product-urls

I changed the url key for the Product

> https://prnt.sc/p9o8li

but on clicking on product it is redirecting to old url.
On clicking product it is going to

> https://ihouzit.com/Timeless-Gin-and-Cocktail-550ml.html url.

What is happening here? Why it is not taking the updated url?

Answer (score 0):

Please go to:

> Marketing -> SEO & Search -> URL Rewrites

and in the grid, filter with **Request Path**: gin-glasses-pasabahce-timeless

Then, Change the **Target Path**

[image]

Comment: Is this the proper way?

Answer (score 0):

One run the following comments

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex 

php bin/magento c:f
```

After check that will be working fine.

Comment: Did this but no effect